# FInd Possible Permutations of Given Numbers whose Multiplication Gives the Required Number

Tags: python, permutation, lcm

**Questions :**
A set of digits S separated by space is passed as input. A number N is also passed as the input. The program must find the two numbers N1, N2 from S so that N1*N2 = N and print them.

**Input Format:**
The set of digits in S separated by space.

**Boundary Conditions:**
The count of digits in S is less than 50.

**Output Format:**
N1 followed by N2 separated by a space(Here N1 >= N2)

**Example Input/Output 1:**

Input:

```
6 8 5 3 9 4
552337
```

Output:

```
859 643
```

Explanation:

```
Using the digits given 859*643 = 552337. As 859 > 643 it is printed first.
```

**Example Input/Output 2:**

Input:

```
2 1 2
42
```

Output:

```
21 2
```

Any possible ideas about how to go about doing this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `itertools.permutations` function. Then it's simply merging the strings, parsing as `int` and multiplying them until you find the right one.

---

Alternatively you can factorize N and then test if the pair of factors contains all the digits in S

```
from itertools import permutations
from numpy import sqrt

def permuts(S,N):
    def factorize(N):
        return [ (i, N//i) for i in xrange(1,int(sqrt(N))) if N%i == 0 ]

    factors = factorize(N)
    for i,j in factors:
        for p in permutations(str(i)+str(j)):
            if ' '.join(map(str, p)) == S:
                return j,i
```

Usage :

```
permuts("2 1 2", 42) -> (21, 2)
```

Comment: The length of the possible multiples is not specified. I could end up going through possible permutation of length from 1 to 50

Comment: I had thought of this answer but i was searching for an alternate one.

Comment: A good alternative but I will wait for another day or 2 to see if a better answer comes else I will mark yours as the answer.